# Display xml generated from a .xml.builder file in a .html.erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, builder

I want to show my users the xml that gets generated for a certain action.

Consider that I have a *PostController* and the following views:

- `/views/posts/show.xml.builder`
- `/views/posts/preview_xml.html.erb`

In my `preview_xml` action I want to be able to parse the show.xml.builder just like if it was called directly and output the result in the html.

I know with **ERB** it is possible with:

```
ERB.new(File.read(path_to_file)).result(bindings)
```

But I have not found a working equivalent for **Builder**

Has anyone else run into this?  Ideas to solve or work around?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out by reading Rails Template engine:

my preview_xml method looks like the following:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  include :Helpers::TagHelper

  def preview_xml
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    xml = ::Builder::XmlMarkup.new(indent: 2)
    builder_file = File.read(::Rails.root.to_s + '/app/views/posts/show.xml.builder')
    require 'builder'
    instance_eval builder_file
    @tag_xml = xml.target!
  end

end
```